# Where does .NET framework code calls to draw a window (native C++)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, mfc, user32

If I use the System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox class' show function to draw a message box, a window pops up. I would like to know where the actual code to draw this window is? Is it in some Win32 API or user32.dll etc.? Through reflector I am unable to see the definition of Show method.

Also, is .NET a wrapper around win32 api then? I know that when we compile .net code it generates IL which is converted to CPU specific instructions at run time and then our CPU executes those instructions. But I have a feeling that there is some common code in Windows OS that's responsible for drawing a window (or reading from text file etc.). All these languages like C++, F#, C#, Java etc. eventually call that code from within the framework. But the question how can I go about finding it and verify it?

For example: in MFC or Win32 whichever function we called to draw a window on the screen, MessageBox.Show also calls the same function but its abstracted from us?

Then on the other hand we can inter operate between two languages.

So I am little confused here. Also I am reading CLR via C# these days so my brain is in super excited state :-)

Comment: Why does it matter where it is implemented? (It most likely just calls the `MessageBox` API)

Comment: While interesting, this doesn't seem on topic to me. You're asking how Microsoft implements functionality, not how to code anything.

Comment: Look up and buy Charles Petzold's WinAPI Bible! The answers are in there Neo!

Comment: I think the question is legitimate: you need to know the layers of the system and how they relate to each other if you want to do anything even moderately complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are on the right track. No matter the language or the framework, at the very bottom is the Operating System, so everything ends there, eventually: system calls.

For example, to open a file in Windows the system call is [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), no matter if you used C `fopen`, C++ `ifstream`, C# `System.IO.*` or Java `java.io.*`.

About your questions of System.Windows.Forms, they use the usual Win32 windows, so the windows are identified by `HWND` values, represented in the CLR as `IntPtr`.

And about the function to show the window, your question is a bit misleading, as there are several functions involved, and several layers in the Win32 API.

For example to create a window, you call `CreateWindowEx()`, to show it if hidden call `ShowWindow()`, and the paint itself will be handled when the window procedure (a callback you have to write) receives the `WM_PAINT` message. But in order to receive messages you have to write a message pump (`GetMessagte() / DispatchMessage()`).

But to create a simple `MessageBox()` there is a function already available that does all that for you: [`MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for which the `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` class is a direct wrapper.

So now, what was the question? Ah, yes, can we interoperate between `System.Windows.Forms` and Win32? **Yes!**

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rodrigo. Just as you gave an example of CreateFile(), then this applies to almost all .net classes/functions (excluding System.Math class and others where you can get things done at the top layer itself) as well. Eventually at some point they go down to the C++ or C code and call stuff there. Basically my goal is to debug all the way down if possible (using windbg/ntsd etc.). I have setup .net symbols from http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=4917) as well so that I can go inside the .net code. I am trying to not be an average developer !!!

Comment: @VVV how did you end up going with this btw?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave - You can use windows debugger to see the call stack all the way up to kernel for creating the file. I haven't used windbg for this exact scenario though but since I used it for other issues, I know that you can use it for this as well.